# Ping class not available in UWP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I think this is a simple problem. I have an IP address and I want to ping it and get its duration. However, in UWP there is no `Ping` class.

How do I ping an IP without this class? Should I connect to a specific port instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the **System.Net.Ping** NuGet package to your project

Comment: yes its a pre-release version, but it did my job. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try to ping Port 80. Normally thats the port you have to use if you are pinging a website.

try this:

```
            HostName host = new HostName("www.google.com");
            var eps = await DatagramSocket.GetEndpointPairsAsync(host , "80");
            if(eps.Count >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: I changed my answer with a sample from a ping function that I made some time ago.
remember to add using Windows.Networking namespace